# Actor with Table placed in a table (LIBGDX)

Tags: java, libgdx

- I have a main Table A
- I have a first Row in Table A with a new Table B
- I have a second Row in Table A with Actor C containing a Table D

The content of Table B and D are equal. The only difference is, that Table D is in a Actor:

Question: Why is the Actor not correct positioned ? It is cenetered to the bottom left of Table A(Table A = blue). Could manually position Actor C, but I would like to understand, whats wrong here.

[image]

Code:

```
Table outerTable = createOuterTable(font, skin);
outerTable.debug();
outerTable.setPosition(200,200);
stage.addActor(outerTable);

private Table createTable_B(BitmapFont font){
    Table table = new Table();
    Label.LabelStyle labelStyle = new Label.LabelStyle(font, new Color(Color.GREEN));
    Label firstlabel = new Label("Table B row 1", labelStyle);
    Label secondlabel = new Label("Table B row 2", labelStyle);
    table.add(firstlabel);
    table.row();
    table.add(secondlabel);
    table.debug();
    return table;
}

private Table createOuterTable(BitmapFont font, Skin skin){
    Table table = new Table();
    TableActor actor_C = new TableActor(skin);
    table.add(createTable_B(font)).pad(20);
    table.row();
    table.add(actor_C).pad(20);
    table.debug();
    return table;
}

public class TableActor extends Group {

    private final BitmapFont font;

    public TableActor(Skin skin) {
        font = skin.get(Label.LabelStyle.class).font;
        Table table = createInnerTable(font);
        addActor(table);
        setTransform(false);
    }

    private Table createInnerTable(BitmapFont font){
        Table table = new Table();

        Label.LabelStyle labelStyle = new Label.LabelStyle(font, new Color(Color.GREEN));
        Label firstlabel = new Label("Table D row 1", labelStyle);
        Label secondlabel = new Label("Table D row 2", labelStyle);

        table.add(firstlabel);
        table.row();
        table.add(secondlabel);
        table.debug();
        return table;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Container` instead of `Group` and check the code in `Container` to understand what's wrong when only using `Group`.